# FORMULA FIELD - Nested IF Statement Getting "Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 5"

Tags: formula-field

Here is the current formula:

```
IF( AND
 (NOT
    (Line_Level_Detail__c ='Services'), Line_Level_Type__c= 'New Product'), UnitPrice   * Quantity , 0)
```

Trying to add criteria that says if the Opportunity Stage is Closed Lost then the results should be 0.

This formula sits on the opportunity product.

This is what I have right now:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName, "Closed Lost"), 0,  AND
 (NOT
    (Line_Level_Detail__c ='Services'), Line_Level_Type__c= 'New Product'), UnitPrice   * Quantity , 0)
```

Can't figure out where we are going wrong.

Comment: Taking some time to break up longer lines (onto separate lines) and indenting is usually a good way to start debugging. It's hard to convey in a comment due to formatting restrictions so, instead, look at [Adrian's answer on this question for an example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201825/formula-field-using-if-and-case?rq=1) of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The three parameters in the IF formulas represent:

1. logical condition
2. value if the condition is true
3. value if the condition is false

Since 0 was the third parameter in your original formula, you can just add another condition to the AND in the original version. Something like the following should return the expected result.

```
IF(AND(NOT(Line_Level_Detail__c ='Services'), Line_Level_Type__c= 'New Product', NOT(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName, 'Closed Lost'))), UnitPrice   * Quantity , 0)
```